# Difference between [(ngModel)]="foo" and #foo in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

`[(ngModel)]="foo"` helps create two-way binding and lets us reference dynamically changing value of foo in the view. But defining `#foo` in the view also has the same effect. So what is the difference between them and which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 2):

[(ngModel)]="foo" creates an instance of FormControl to track user input, validation and status and #foo is a local reference to current DOM element/directive within a template. ngModel directive sets this #foo reference to itself by adding #foo="ngModel" to the element.

You can access native element in component as:

```
   @ViewChild('foo') foo;
```

and NgModel in the component as:

```
  @ViewChild('foo', {read: NgModel}) foo;
```